# Why IList<T> does not contain a Length property?

Tags: c#

I tried to do this:

```
int listAverage = NumberList.Sum()/NumberList.Length;
```

where `NumberList` is an `IList`. It throws an error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

That gets me thinking, [why does `List<T>` not have a `Length` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc0h48wd(v=vs.110).aspx)? I know you can use `Count()` instead, but `Length` has an O(1) time complexity.

Comment: Because it has a `Count` property...

Comment: `Count` is `O(1)` if the `IList` is actually a list.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: According to the question `NumberList` is an `IList` not a `List`, so while it's probably actually a `List` and is actually `O(1)` (per the docs), it's not necessarily the case.

Comment: As to why the change in terminology from `Length` to `Count`, you'd have to ask the .NET team. I'm guessing they decided that `Length` didn't really accurately describe the `Count` in some types of collections.

Comment: Also FYI [Enumerable.Average](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: My guess is it's because arrays have a length meant to be a fixed number, where a `List<T>`'s count is mutable, and to maybe help differentiate between an array and List.

Comment: @MattBurland: Yep, I accidentally went to the `List<T>` docs

Comment: @DrewKennedy: Maybe, but you can resize an array with `Array.Resize`, although I believe it's just creating a new array and copying.

Comment: @MattBurland Yep. This point is exactly why I was careful to say "meant to be a fixed number" :)

Comment: @TimothyShields thanks! That works better.

Comment: @DrewKennedy: It's probably more due to the idea that array and string are continuous, so a `Length` property makes sense. While `Count` comes from `ICollection` and `Count()` is an extension method of `IEnumerable`. It doesn't really make sense to talk about the `Length` of a `Stack` or especially the `Length` of a queue (which could be confused with it's capacity) or the `Length` of a dictionary. So `Count` seems like the more general term to refer to how many things are in a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my experience, the convention in .NET seems to be that arrays and strings have the `Length` property, and higher level countable collections have `Count` property. The `IList<T>` has a `Count` property which is in general **should be** O(1), but depends on the exact implementation. For example the most used `List<T>` does it definitely at O(1).

The generic `Count()` method is an extension for any `IEnumerable<T>` type, and that has technically O(n) complexity indeed, because the number of items may not be known before enumerating every element, or giving the number requires some custom processing (like for example a Linq to SQL query result expressed by an `IQueryable<T>` interface).

Comment: Can you provide a source that supports your statement "*The convenction in .NET is that arrays and strings have Length, and higher level countable collections have Count property*"?

Comment: Okay thanks, I think that might be wisest. While I don't necessarily disagree, I have not yet come across any recommendation or discussion on the topic that would warrant it to be considered a convention.